# What is the Dart/Flutter equivalent of PHP's gmmktime()?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

I need to calculate the value in Dart/Flutter, as calculated by the [gmmktime() function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmmktime.php) in PHP.

This is what I was trying till now:

```
var ms = (DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch)/100;
int ms = DateTime.now().toUtc().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
```

But both of these approaches give a value, which is not expected by this API in its header, here: https://api.kitewalk.com/#authentication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP's `gmmktime` is documented to return "[Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)", which is the number of *seconds* since the the "Unix epoch".

Your first approach was almost right, but you didn't convert from *milli*seconds to seconds correctly.  There are 1000 milliseconds in a second, so you need to divide by 1000, not 100.  Additionally, whatever you're passing the time to probably expects an integral number of seconds and not a floating point value, so you'll need to use integer division or round the quotient afterward.

Also note that the "Unix epoch" is not time-zone dependent; [`DateTime.millisecondsSinceEpoch`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.4.1/dart-core/DateTime/millisecondsSinceEpoch.html) already measures against a fixed point in time, so an explicit conversion to UTC isn't necessary (but it doesn't hurt).

A correct version would be:

```dart
var unixTime = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch ~/ 1000;
```